# Function template parameter compilation error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template <size_t A>
class Test {
    public:
        typedef array<int, A> TestType;
};

template <size_t A>
void foo(Test<A>::TestType t) {
    cout << "test\n";
}

int main() {
    Test<5>::TestType q;

    foo(q);
    return 0;
}
```

but foo doesn't compile. In gcc I get

```
prog.cpp:12:19: error: variable or field ‘foo’ declared void
 void foo(Test<A>::TestType t) {
                   ^
prog.cpp:12:28: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘t’
 void foo(Test<A>::TestType t) {
```

while in Visual Studio 2010 I get

```
error C2975: 'Test' : invalid template argument for 'A', expected compile-time constant expression
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, as A is a compile-time constant. What should I change?

Comment: It has to be `typename Test<A>::TestType`, because it's a dependent name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would add `typename` like this:

```
template <size_t A>
void foo(typename Test<A>::TestType t) {
    cout << "test\n";
}
```

the only effect is a better error message. The problem is that you still can not deduce template parameters like that.

When you declare `q`

```
Test<5>::TestType q;
```

`q`'s type is `std::array<int,5>` and the compiler doesn't know how this type was connected to `Test<5>`. In the call to `foo(q)` it would need a much deeper analysis of the code which is not standardized to figure out that there is only one possible match for `A`. You need to call

```
foo<5>(q);
```

to specify it explicitly or change the definition of `foo`:

```
template <size_t A>
void foo(std::array<int,A> t) {
    cout << "test\n";
}
```